# Can't make postgresql load at startup in Mac OS

Tags: macos, postgresql, service, postgresql-9.3, launchd

I have installed `postgresql` via `HomeBrew`. It worked but today I find that `postgresql` server does not run when computer start.

I try to use `launchctl` to load it again with below command:

```
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

and I see the message:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: Service is disabled
```

I do not know how to enable postgresql service. Could anyone show me?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use `-w` option with `launchctl`.

```
$ launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

`-w`       Overrides the Disabled key and sets it to false.

Comment: In Yosemite that should be `launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`.

Comment: Where does `-w` put the "Disabled" override? After running this command, I can't find it in `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist`.

Comment: However, how did that get disabled in the first place though? Ran into the same problem for no apparent reason, just curious...

Comment: Avoiding a me-too here, but Googling for a similar problem with redis brought me to this page and answer.  the `-w` works for redis as well

Answer (score 5):

The new way as `brew info postgresql` says:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

It might also be helpful to use the command `brew info postgresql` for suggestions about how to set up your database and move the plist file into `~/Library/LaunchAgents`